# simple z-index not working as i expect in my case

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I am prepending elements with jquery. Here is what I add:

```
  <span class="author">AUTHOR: Ayuidasht</span>
```

im trying to get it to be above the other text, but it is still not working with z-index.

```
.author {
    color:red;
    font-family:"Drone";
    z-index:99999;
  background-font:green;
}
```

Comment: The z-index attribute is ignored for any element that does not have a position attribute. Try adding position: relative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do yo mean to 'cover up' the other text? It would need to be positioned absolutely

```
.author {
   ...; 
  position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: just what I needed thanks. works like a charm i used relative

Answer (score 0):

z-index works with `position: absolute`. Hope it helps!